# `solana stakes` CLI command

Tags: cli, staking

Here I have the results from the `solana stakes <insert validator>` CLI command.

```
{
    "stakePubkey": "47YYxhvHBg2RwDRMFnTh3v2x9wiBp4GwkV3yewNZLsw9",
    "stakeType": "Stake",
    "accountBalance": 100188135717,
    "creditsObserved": 762614,
    "delegatedStake": 100185852837,
    "delegatedVoteAccountAddress": "3nHRjY8y9koWkEzKsh6i4tSmiyYFBXMMiMhZDHLbDcam",
    "activationEpoch": 327,
    "staker": "BYy9ZGnwDaeWPiu6KTjFVPKYcSk3z4QWethGHGQyMt3h",
    "withdrawer": "H6ce5MfQq4qNZpN42QJVb11KFhUAQYWaoRw8qxs8PCpf",
    "rentExemptReserve": 2282880,
    "activeStake": 100185852837
  },
```

Would someone mind explaining the different key/value pairs and their meaning? Looking to track the **delegated/active** stake, but sometimes the "activeStake" is missing from some delegators, so I'm also wondering about the significance of that.

Currently, I see that active and delegated are the same, so should I assume them to be equivalent? Just confused because why would there be different keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a succinct representation of a stake account and its [state](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/0fff5b8bf86721ec88bb69d142a41cc12f6a6cf9/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L19-L26).

I'll annotate inline, but reordered for clarity

1. Available in all states

   - `"stakePubkey": "47YYxhvHBg2RwDRMFnTh3v2x9wiBp4GwkV3yewNZLsw9",`

     The stake account's address
   - `"accountBalance": 100188135717,`

     The account's lamports balance (ie. `AccountInfo::lamports`)
   - `"stakeType": "Stake",`

     The current [`StakeState`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/0fff5b8bf86721ec88bb69d142a41cc12f6a6cf9/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L19-L26) of the account. One of:

     - `Uninitialized` - account has been allocated, but no `StakeInstruction::Initialized` issued against it. Anyone could assume control of an account in this state, so the aforementioned instruction is typically issued in the same transaction that allocates the account.
     - `Initialized` - Owner has assumed control of the account, but not yet delegated it to a validator
     - `Stake` - The account has been delegated and is in one of the following (implicit) sub-states depending on epochs since (de)activation epoch and total (transient) stake changing state at a given epoch boundary

       - `activating` - During the activation epoch or after, but global transient stake limit has been exceeded (partially active)
       - `active` - The full delegation has been activated
       - `deactivating` - During the deactivation epoch or after, but the global transient stake limit has been exceeded (partially deactivated)
       - `inactive` - The full delegation has been deactivated
     - `RewardsPool` - Defunct, unimplemented delegation pooling mechanism.  See [stake pools](https://spl.solana.com/stake-pool) instead
2. Available in `Initialized` or `Stake` states

   - `"staker": "BYy9ZGnwDaeWPiu6KTjFVPKYcSk3z4QWethGHGQyMt3h",`

     Pubkey of signing authority which controls delegation. May update itself
   - `"withdrawer": "H6ce5MfQq4qNZpN42QJVb11KFhUAQYWaoRw8qxs8PCpf",`

     Pubkey of signing authority which may withdraw inactive stake or undelegated lamports. May update itself *or* the staker authority.
   - `"rentExemptReserve": 2282880,`

     Lamport balance required to keep the account rent-exempt. *Not* counted towards delegation
   - `"unixTimestamp": 1658565237,`

     (not in example) If the account is subject to lockup, the optional block time after which the account is unlocked
   - `"epoch": 123,`

     (not in example) If the account is subject to lockup, the optional epoch at which the account is unlocked
   - `"custodian": "3N5VLFDu5ycWaK5w7fpnpDqPqbkyeeC3xbrvQ9oZdm64",`

     (not in example) If the account is subject to lockup, the signing authority able to modify the lockup terms and approve withdraws
3. Available only in `Stake` state

   - `"activationEpoch": 327,`

     Epoch during which the account was last delegated
   - `"deactivationEpoch": 420,`

     (not in example) Epoch which the account was marked for deactivation
   - `"delegatedVoteAccountAddress": "3nHRjY8y9koWkEzKsh6i4tSmiyYFBXMMiMhZDHLbDcam",`

     Address of the chosen validator's vote account
   - `"creditsObserved": 762614,`

     Number of vote credits the validator had at the last epoch boundary.  Used to account epoch rewards that this delegation is entitled to receive.
   - `"delegatedStake": 100185852837,`

     Total lamports in the delegation, regardless of sub-state
   - `"activeStake": 100185852837,`

     In `activating`, `active` and `deactivating` sub-states, the portion of the delegation which is fully activated
   - `"activatingStake": 123456789,`

     (not in example) In the `activating` sub-state, the portion of the delegation that has not yet been activated
   - `"deactivatingStake": 123456789,`

     (not in example) In the `deactivating` sub-state, the portion of the delegation that is still active